# Program printing a number a certain times instead of multiplying

Tags: python

I’ve written a piece of code that instead of print the product, prints a number a certain number of times. Whats wrong with it?

```
twelve = 12
name = input("What is your name? \nAnswer:  ")
print("Cool name!")
nums = input("\n\nHow much pocket money did you receive last month?\nAnswer:  ")
total = nums * twelve
print("\n\nI think you get ",  total + " pounds in pocket money per year! Nice!")
```

Comment: `nums` is a string. You should convert it to a number first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that your `nums` variable is a string, which is the default with all Python inputs. Try converting it to `int`:

```py
nums = int(input(...))
```

Or float if you are inputting a floating point number.